# Replace Part of String in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

If i have data in my MySQL like this

> table:
>
> data(TEXT)
>
> foo (hal)
>
> foo (dave)
>
> bar (dave)
>
> bar(dave)

And i want to do This Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT(data) FROM table;
```

Now this will return the table as listed above. But i want to do is some sort of replace so that my return query should look like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT(data) FROM table Replace(data, "(xxxx)", "");
```

So the Query returns

- foo
- bar

Obviously the data is not replaced because the Brackets are important, its just replaced for the query

If this can be done is there performance pitfals in this

Comment: can you post your table schema and maybe some sample data so we have a better understanding of what you are trying to do. Also, it sounds like from what you posted, you may be better off with a LIKE query. REPLACE will definitely impact performance

Comment: As shown above. The table name is 'table' and it has one column 'data' Where the fields are shown above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT stuff 
FROM (
  SELECT RTRIM(SUBSTR(data, 1, LOCATE('(', data) - 1)) AS stuff 
  FROM foo
) t;
```

Comment: The RTRIM is optional. It strips trailing spaces from your data.

Comment: LOCATE('(', data) - 1) Im having probs on that

Comment: It works just fine. We can't help you if you just say "Im having problems"

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me for the above problem. Thanks hobodave, you did put me to the right direction

```
SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data, '(', 1)) AS tag FROM table
```